# IE version 8.07 Session Lost on Hyperlink click within authenticated session (asp.net)

Tags: session, internet-explorer-8

After logging in (authorization) within my application a session is created and I am being redirected to correct location (SSL page).  However, after clicking on a hyperlink (non SSL page within same application) I am being logged out automatically (authenticated session lost).  I tested the same in FireFox 3.6 and the application is working as expected.

The above is only happening if i clear the chache from IE and log in.  However, if I login for second time after just closing the browser the above does not occur.

Thanks,

Lihnid

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `<forms requireSSL="" />` property set to **true** in your web.config?

If so, you may need to set it to **false** if you want the Forms Authentication cookie to be sent for SSL and non-SSL encrypted pages.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.requiressl.aspx

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.  Tried the above and the issue still occurs

Answer (score 0):

What do your URLs look like before login and after login?  This kinda thing happened to me before, and it turned out that my authn cookies were having trouble with a domain change from www.domain.com to domain.com or visa versa.

Comment: HI Wes P. Urls are ok. the only difference is SSL to Non-SSL.  As above it only happens once if i have cleared the cache